# Dont post the form if the "caseref" field has less than 10 characters

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help please?

I cannot get this to work, all I need the form to do is not post if the "caseref" field has less than 10 characters in it, the html is:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Update</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" action="update.php">
<table height="408" width="527">
<tr>
<td height="25" width="334"><font face="Calibri" size="6">Case Ref:<br>
    <input type="text" name="caseref" size="25" maxlength="13 value="">    </font></td>
</tr>
 <tr>

  <td height="25" width="334"><font face="Calibri" size="6">Engineers Name:<br>
    <select name="name">
    <option value="Dave" selected>Dave</option>
    <option value="Terry">Terry</option>
<option value="Piere">Piere</option>
    <option value="Steve">Steve</option>
    <option value="Craig">Craig</option>
<option value="Faz">Faz</option>


    </select></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="164" width="334"><font face="Calibri" size="6">Update:<br>
    <textarea cols="17" name="notes" rows="10"></textarea></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="27" width="475">
    <div align="center">
      <p align="left"><font face="Calibri" size="6"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></font></p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

So if the case ref field has less than 10 chars then it needs to post a messagebox saying "please try again!"

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here's a hint, try looking into the form [onsubmit](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html) event. You can use the inline `onsubmit` attribute, or attach an event handler in your JavaScript for it (preferred), and then have it call a function that checks the length of the field, returning true if it's long enough, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is change the `<input type="submit" value="submit">` to a normal button with an onclick function.
In this function you can use javascript to check the length of the ref field and react accordingly.

You can check a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7w9s5z3w/)

Comment: Here you go. I used JQuery instead of standard JS since i find it more readable but it is easy to transform it to normal JS. For the alert you can make it nicer by using an error div and place some error msg inside it like netzach showed in his answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="caseref" size="25" maxlength="13" id="caseref" value="">
```

Hi, you can use jQuery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type="submit"]').on("click",function(){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default
    var myLength = $("#caseref").val().length;
    if(myLength > 10){
     $('#form').submit();
    }else{
      $('#message').html("Please, try again");
    }
});
</script>
```

You can change the submit button for a link like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
<!-- change for-->
<a href="javascript:;" id="button">Send</a>
```

Also replace your form header

```
<form method="POST" id="form" action="update.php">
```

Then you change the on click event for

```
$('#button').on("click",function(){
    var myLength = $("#caseref").val().length;
    if(myLength > 10){
     $('#form').submit();
    }else{
      $('#message').html("Please, try again");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am a total newbie to coding, where do these bit of codes go? sorry :o

Comment: Hi, you need replace your code for example, replace an input for a link.
You can Copy and past the on.("click"), you need include jquery, is the second block in my answer, you can copy and paste this beetween the <body> tags, after to close. Consider modify the submit for the link.